# Segmentation fault in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Basically I want to get user's input and tokenize it. For example I type
`4 <tab> 5 <tab> 6`
I want to get just

```
4
5
6
```

But my piece of code does not work ;(

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    char str;
    scanf("%c",&str);
    char *p = strtok(str, "\t");
    while(p != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", p);
        p = strtok(NULL, "\t");
    }
}
```

Comment: `strtok` needs a string (`char*`) as the first argument, not a character. VERY fundamental C concepts at work here...

Comment: A much more fundamental concept is the fact that you can only store one character in a `char`, you're never going to be able to stuff `"4\t5\t6\n"` in there.

Answer (score 5):

You are getting mixed up between `char` and `char*`.

Try this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    char str[1000];
    while(scanf("%s", str)) {
        printf("%s\n", str);
    }
}
```

1000 is the maximum length of a single token. Adjust as necessary.

Comment: I dont have max length though....what is difference of char* and char?? I know that char* is a pointer to smth...But how it works it general??

Comment: Are you sure that a *token* has no maximum length? That is still is a solvable problem, but the solution is a little longer.

Comment: And `char*` is a pointer to a `char`. Sometimes it points to just one `char`; sometimes it points to the first `char` in an array of `char`s. The difference between these two situations is semantic (i.e. not in the data type).

Comment: lol it seems like this piece code does not work))

Comment: Apologies. I missed a variable name while refactoring the code. Fixed.